# How to get a particular word from the sentence?

Tags: jquery, html

I have input value like below:

```
<input type="text" value: "Part: PT001 Invoice: 1234" />
```

what I need is I want to get the part number alone "PT001" from the value of the input..

Note: PT001 is dynamically getting value...

Appreciate your thoughts...

Comment: jQuery not required, What you need is a regular expression, or, perhaps even just string splitting if the string is consistent.

Comment: @Adam then how you get this look at the answers... match functions are also from using js files.. I think you are not good in jquery and javascript

Comment: In HTML 5, it is totally valid to have custom attributes prefixed with data-, e.g., <input data-partNo="Your dynamic part no" type="text" value: "Part: PT001 Invoice: 1234" /> and get the part number using $(this).data('partNo ');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex [`/\bPart:\s?(\S+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/2Ae0o0/1) and get the capturing group value.

```js
console.log(
  $('input').val().match(/\bPart:\s?(\S+)/)[1]
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Part: PT001 Invoice: 1234" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string pattern remains the same for all cases -

Give an `id` to your textbox

```
<input type="text" id="myTb" value="Part: PT001 Invoice: 1234" />
```

Then using jQuery: (long version for the sake of simplicity)

```
var full_string = $('#myTb').val();
var explode = full_string.split(':'); // split the string based on :

// explode[0] will contain "Part"
// explode[1] will contain " PT001 Invoice"
// explode[3] will contain " 1234"

var part_explode = explode[1].split(" "); // split by blank space

// similarly, part_explode[0] will be blank space
// part_explode[1] will contain "PT001"
// part_explode[2] will contain "Invoice"
console.log(part_explode[1]); // should be PT001
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0kqe16bh/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If PT is consistent then use:

```
$('input').val().match(/PT\d+/);
```

It will return PT and 1 or more digits. i.e. PT100

Comment: No PT also no consistent it will change